# Delete line fromo CSV file where columns is not specific string

Tags: linux, command-line, csv

I have this CSV file:

```
"mikecook1966","6days","","Classy1","7/2020"
"kyndrion","1min","","Doominator handle","7/2020"
"Ataca","Feb2,2020","","Soporte 30.5x30.5 VTX-DVR Speedy Bee","7/2020"
```

I would like to leave in output results, where column 2 contains `2020`.

Example output:

```
"Ataca","Feb2,2020","","Soporte 30.5x30.5 VTX-DVR Speedy Bee","7/2020"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your CSV doesn't include escaped double quotes, you can use grep:

```
grep '^"[^"]*","[^"]*2020' file.csv
```

For more complex CSV, a CSV-aware tool is needed.

```
perl -MText::CSV_XS=csv -e 'csv( in     => "file.csv",
                                 filter => { 2 => sub{ /2020/ } } )'
```